# NAnt equvalent of <propertyfile> element

Tags: ant, nant

What will be the NAnt equivalent of the below script? This script is in Ant.

```
<target name="getVersion">
    <propertyfile file="./version.properties">
        <entry key="version" type="string" value="${buildVersion}"/>
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<include>` task. The documentation is [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/include.html). The contents of the include file should be in the form of xml not value pairs as in java. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Project Properties" default="">
  <property name="dotnet-version" value="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"/>  
  <property name="output-dir" value="c:\working\testproj\out"/>
  <property name="temp-dir" value="C:\temp"/>
</project>
```